# How to replace submit in form with jquery change attribute?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Guys i have this sample form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/some/url/method-to-handle-the-form">
some stuff here.

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

The original function was the submit button needs to be clicked to load that action, what I want to do is to make it automatic adding this select type:

```
<select blah blah>
```

That whenever i choose something in it, the form will be submitted along with the option i chose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give an id to your form, in case of multiple forms

```
<form method="POST" action="/some/url/method-to-handle-the-form" id="someid">
```

then do submit on change of select for that form

```
$('#selectElementId').change(
function(){
     $("#someid").submit();
      });
```

Answer (score 4):

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aU75h/)

```
$('#selectElementId').change(
    function(){
         $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
         /* or:
         $('#formElementId').trigger('submit');
            or:
         $('#formElementId').submit();
         */
    });
```

Comment: what if there are two forms in the page? what happens in the closest form part?

Comment: `closest` will find the closest form to drop-down list n trigger submit

Answer (score 1):

Try this demo http://jsfiddle.net/HTVMw/4/

```
<form method="POST" action="/some/url/method-to-handle-the-form">
    some stuff here.
    <select name="select" id="select">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

```
$(function(){
    var $select = $('#select');
    $select.change(function(){
       $select.closest('form').submit(); 
    });
});
```